# Exclude generated by dagger2 class from apk

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have abstract `FirstClass`, and his child class `SecondClass`
In second class I have dagger inject:

```
component.inject(this);
```

But `_MembersInjector` generate for this two classes — `FirstClass_MembersInjector` and `SecondClass_MembersInjector`

How can I exclude `FirstClass_MembersInjector` from my build?

Comment: Why do you need that? What is your use-case?

Comment: I simplify my example, but at all looks like this: i have core library, two component libraries which use core lib, and big project which use this libs and core. Dagger generate MembersInjector for class from core in two libraries and gives me duplicate entry exception in main project @azizbekian

Comment: Can you please delete or merge your old similar (duplicate) question -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45416388/5241933

Comment: @DavidRawson It's visually similar questions, but it's about different siolutions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like:

```
class FirstClass {

    @Inject Integer firstClassField;

}
```

then:

```
class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

    @Inject String secondClassField;

    void injectMembers() {
        DaggerComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Dagger 2 generates members injectors for all classes with `@Inject` annotated fields i.e., candidates for property injection. This is regardless of whether you are actually requesting injection for that class somewhere in your code or not.

In the contrived example above, the `FirstClass_MembersInjector` will be generated even though it is not used in the generated Dagger Component.

The solution to your problem probably lies with better organisation your project rather than trying to configure unusual behaviour for Dagger 2.

Comment: it's almost like my case, but there is one difference. In my case there is another one class in the hierarchy of inheritance between `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` without any injectable members. I'll call it `FirstAndHalfClass`. And for this class I don't want to have a `_MembersInjector`

Comment: @winston I don't think preventing the generation of the `_MembersInjector` is the answer to that problem - it sounds like it is better to try and refactor and rename